# How to redirect into a route after inserting data in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a detail view that shows info from a register, but it's a post route that gets the id from the request that i send in a value of a button.

Now i have another view that register data to a table but i want to redirect me to the detail view after i do the insert.

#### My attempt:

```
public function newContract(Request $request){
        /// insert code
       return $this->detailContract($request);
    }
```

#### Route:

```
Route::post('newcontract', 'contractcontroller@newContract')->name('new.contract');
Route::post('detailcontract', 'contractcontroller@detailContract')->name('detail.contract');
```

#### Error

> "get route it's not allowed"

I'm using DB, and not eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Web.php

U can it  redirect()->route('name')

I changed post and writed get method

```
Route::get('detailcontract/{data}', 'contractcontroller@detailContract')->name('detail.contract');
```

Controller

```
public function newContract(Request $request){
        /// insert code
       return redirect()->route('detail.contract',['data'=>'foo blabla']);
    }
```

Comment: why especially post ?

Answer (score 0):

return view

```
 return view('view_folder_name/view_file_name');
```